# Webpack don't rebuild on css change, missing some setting?

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm set postcss-loader + style-loader on webpack, and I'am using webpack-dev-server, but every time that change css, the webpack don't rebuild.

**script webpack dev server I use on scripts npm:**

```
webpack-dev-server --hot
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const lost = require('lost')
const mqpacker = require('css-mqpacker')
const precss = require('precss')
const cssnano = require('cssnano')
const nested = require('postcss-nested')
const cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext')
const atImport = require('postcss-import')
const postCSSFocus = require('postcss-focus')
const pxtorem = require('postcss-pxtorem')
const flexBugsFixes = require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes')
const rucksack = require('rucksack-css')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const objectFit = require('postcss-object-fit-images')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const StatsPlugin = require('stats-webpack-plugin')

const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV

module.exports = {

  devServer: {
    colors: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: false,
    port: 8080,
  },

  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server?reload=true',
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/script/app.js')
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build/'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.css', '.json']
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].min.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true
      }
    }),
    new StatsPlugin('webpack.stats.json', {
      source: false,
      modules: false
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      context: 'src/svg',
      from: '*.svg',
      to: 'svg'
    }])
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.worker\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel!worker?inline!'
    }, {
      test: /\.js?$/,
      exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.worker\.js$/],
      loader: 'babel'
    }, {
      test: /\.mod\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules!postcss')
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: /\.mod\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader')
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|svg|gif)$/,
      loaders: [
        'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
        'image-webpack?{progressive:true, optimizationLevel: 7, interlaced: false, pngquant:{quality: "65-90", speed: 4}}'
      ]
    }, {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }, {
      test: /\.woff$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }, {
      test: /\.woff2$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }, {
      test: /\.[ot]tf$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }, {
      test: /\.eot$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
    }],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.css', '.json']
    }
  },

  postcss: compiler => [
    atImport({
      addDependencyTo: compiler
    }),
    precss,
    cssnext({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    }),
    pxtorem({
      propWhiteList: ['font', 'font-size', 'line-height', 'letter-spacing'],
      selectorBlackList: []
    }),
    lost,
    postCSSFocus,
    flexBugsFixes,
    rucksack,
    objectFit,
    nested,
    mqpacker,
    cssnano({
      autoprefixer: false
    })
  ]
}
```

Lack configure something? Because in Webpack documentation, can not find anything about

Answer (score 0):

Did you require the css file in your main javascript file? For example, in your index.jsx:

```
require("somestyle.css");
```

css-loader will only know about the CSS files that the application has required.  For more information, see: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader

Comment: yep, i'm require the css file on app.js, but anyway don't rebuild.